# Toggle a checkbox into quasar q-table

Tags: quasar-framework

I am trying to edit a checkbox into quasar q-table.

I have created a codepen: https://codepen.io/luizalves/pen/PoXpBrV?editors=101

My problem is when I click the checkbox, it´s not changing.

I´d like the checkbox changing when I click and a event to save it in a DB.

// markup

```
<div id="q-app" style="min-height: 100vh;">
<div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-table
      flat bordered
      title="Treats"
      :rows="rows"
      :columns="columns"
      row-key="name"
      binary-state-sort
    >
      <template v-slot:body="props">
        <q-tr :props="props">
          <q-td key="name" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.name }}
            <q-popup-edit v-model="props.row.name" v-slot="scope">
              <q-input v-model="scope.value" dense autofocus counter @keyup.enter="scope.set"></q-input>
            </q-popup-edit>
          </q-td>
           <q-td key="isBlackListed" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.isBlackListed }}
             <q-popup-edit
              v-model="props.row.isBlackListed"
              buttons
              v-slot="scope"
            >
              <q-checkbox
                v-model="scope.isBlackListed"
                dense
                label="BlackListed"
                autofocus
                @click="scope.isBlackListed = !scope.isBlackListed"
              />
            </q-popup-edit>
           </q-td>        
          <q-td key="calories" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.calories }}
            <q-popup-edit v-model="props.row.calories" title="Update calories" buttons v-slot="scope">
              <q-input type="number" v-model="scope.value" dense autofocus></q-input>
            </q-popup-edit>
          </q-td>
          <q-td key="fat" :props="props">
            <div class="text-pre-wrap">{{ props.row.fat }}</div>
            <q-popup-edit v-model="props.row.fat" v-slot="scope">
              <q-input type="textarea" v-model="scope.value" dense autofocus></q-input>
            </q-popup-edit>
          </q-td>
          <q-td key="carbs" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.carbs }}
            <q-popup-edit v-model="props.row.carbs" title="Update carbs" buttons persistent v-slot="scope">
              <q-input type="number" v-model="scope.value" dense autofocus hint="Use buttons to close"></q-input>
            </q-popup-edit>
          </q-td>
          <q-td key="protein" :props="props">{{ props.row.protein }}</q-td>
          <q-td key="sodium" :props="props">{{ props.row.sodium }}</q-td>
          <q-td key="calcium" :props="props">{{ props.row.calcium }}</q-td>
          <q-td key="iron" :props="props">{{ props.row.iron }}</q-td>
        </q-tr>
      </template>
    </q-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

// script

```
const { ref } = Vue

const columns = [
  {
    name: 'name',
    required: true,
    label: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
    align: 'left',
    field: row => row.name,
    format: val => `${val}`,
    sortable: true
  },
  { name: 'isBlackListed', align: 'center', label: 'BlackListed', field: 'isBlackListed', sortable: false },
  { name: 'calories', align: 'center', label: 'Calories', field: 'calories', sortable: true },
  { name: 'fat', label: 'Fat (g)', field: 'fat', sortable: true, style: 'width: 10px' },
  { name: 'carbs', label: 'Carbs (g)', field: 'carbs' },
  { name: 'protein', label: 'Protein (g)', field: 'protein' },
  { name: 'sodium', label: 'Sodium (mg)', field: 'sodium' },
  { name: 'calcium', label: 'Calcium (%)', field: 'calcium', sortable: true, sort: (a, b) => parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10) },
  { name: 'iron', label: 'Iron (%)', field: 'iron', sortable: true, sort: (a, b) => parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10) }
]

const rows = [
  {
    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
    isBlackListed:false,
    calories: 159,
    fat: 6.0,
    carbs: 24,
    protein: 4.0,
    sodium: 87,
    calcium: '14%',
    iron: '1%'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
    isBlackListed:false,
    calories: 237,
    fat: 9.0,
    carbs: 37,
    protein: 4.3,
    sodium: 129,
    calcium: '8%',
    iron: '1%'
  },
  {
    name: 'Eclair',
    isBlackListed:false,
    calories: 262,
    fat: 16.0,
    carbs: 23,
    protein: 6.0,
    sodium: 337,
    calcium: '6%',
    iron: '7%'
  },
  {
    name: 'Cupcake',
    isBlackListed:false,
    calories: 305,
    fat: 3.7,
    carbs: 67,
    protein: 4.3,
    sodium: 413,
    calcium: '3%',
    iron: '8%'
  },
  {
    name: 'Gingerbread',
    isBlackListed:false,
    calories: 356,
    fat: 16.0,
    carbs: 49,
    protein: 3.9,
    sodium: 327,
    calcium: '7%',
    iron: '16%'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jelly bean',
    isBlackListed:false,
    calories: 375,
    fat: 0.0,
    carbs: 94,
    protein: 0.0,
    sodium: 50,
    calcium: '0%',
    iron: '0%'
  },
  {
    name: 'Lollipop',
    isBlackListed:false,
    calories: 392,
    fat: 0.2,
    carbs: 98,
    protein: 0,
    sodium: 38,
    calcium: '0%',
    iron: '2%'
  },
  {
    name: 'Honeycomb',
    isBlackListed:false,
    calories: 408,
    fat: 3.2,
    carbs: 87,
    protein: 6.5,
    sodium: 562,
    calcium: '0%',
    iron: '45%'
  },
  {
    name: 'Donut',
    isBlackListed:false,
    calories: 452,
    fat: 25.0,
    carbs: 51,
    protein: 4.9,
    sodium: 326,
    calcium: '2%',
    iron: '22%'
  },
  {
    name: 'KitKat',
    isBlackListed:false,
    calories: 518,
    fat: 26.0,
    carbs: 65,
    protein: 7,
    sodium: 54,
    calcium: '12%',
    iron: '6%'
  }
]

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
    return {
      columns,
      rows: ref(rows)
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} })
app.mount('#q-app')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `scope.value` and it will work.

Codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/qBLrePK

```
<q-popup-edit
          v-model="props.row.isBlackListed"
          buttons
          v-slot="scope"
        >
          <q-checkbox
            v-model="scope.value"
            dense
            label="BlackListed"
            autofocus
          />
        </q-popup-edit>
```